# How many pages should I do as mockups in web design?

Tags: website-design, mockup

Let's say we've mapped out the sitemap and there are about 10 pages. How many of those pages should I create as mockups? Of course, it's a given that there should be the landing page. But aside from the landing page, what other pages should I create (keeping in mind that none of the mockups I give will be final)?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on the site, the contract, and the preferences of the company designing the website. As such I'm voting to close this question

Answer (score 1):

It would have helped to know the sitemap, it's very important to know what pages with what functionality you will have and isolate only 3 of them. Aside from homepage, 2 other pages should be presented. Especially since they are not final.

Basically just show your most powerful and iconic 3 pages.
That's how I usually present my work.